# Get a list of related objects in model's __str__

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models with One-to-Many relationship; Listing, and Bids.
Is it possible to retrieve and display a list of Bid objects' bid_price in Listing's str method?

The code provided below crashes the server and I am not sure of the correct keywords to search for.

I understand how listing.bid_set works in the Shell or view, but I am not sure how to make it work here.

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        bid_objects = Bid.objects.all().filter(listing__id=self.id)
        price_list = []
        for bid_object in bid_objects:
            price_list.append(bid_object.bid_price)
        return f"{self.title}, {price_list}"

class Bid(models.Model): 
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing_bids")
    bid_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you specified `related_name='listing_bids'`, it means you access the related `Bid`s with `self.listing_bids`:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        bid_objects = self.listing_bids.values_list('bid_price', flat=True)
        return f'{self.title}, {bid_objects}'
```

Comment: If you don't specify a related_name, Django automatically creates one using the name of your model with the suffix _set

Comment: I get it now, in my case, bid_set will work if I don't specify related_name. Thanks for your answer.